# How can I determine that exactly other page already loaded in Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I have two pages like below:

***The first page:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="page-info">This is first page</h1>
    <a class="link-line" href="/second_page/">Go to second page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

***The second page:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Second Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="page-info">This is second page</h1>
    <a class="link-line" href="/first_page/">Back to first page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the first page when I click to ***a*** tag, browser will load the second page. How can I determine that exactly the second page already loaded.

***I have tried***:

```
describe("Test Load New Page", () => {
    it("should load second page", () => {
        browser.url('/first_page/');

        const pageInfoSelector1 = ".page-info";
        browser.waitForVisible(pageInfoSelector1);

        const pageInfo1 = browser.getText(pageInfoSelector1);
        assert.equal(pageInfo1, "This is first page");

        const aTag = ".link-line";
        browser.waitForEnabled(aTag);
        browser.click(aTag);

        const pageInfoSelector2 = ".page-info";
        browser.waitForVisible(pageInfoSelector2); 

        const pageInfo2 = browser.getText(pageInfoSelector2);
        assert.equal(pageInfo2, "This is second page"); // Error here: AssertError: Can not assert "This is first page" == "This is second page"
    });
});
```

Error: `AssertError: Can not assert "This is first page" == "This is second page"`.

It mean `const pageInfo2 = browser.getText(pageInfoSelector2);` has got text of ***h1*** tag in the first page instead of the second page.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `browser.waitForExist(pageInfoSelector2, 10000);` or a combination of previous one and `browser.waitForText(pageInfoSelector2, 10000);`

Comment: Thanks for reply my question but it still not working too. :(

Comment: whats the error, share more information. try without using `pageInfoSelector2 ` like `browser.getText('h1=This is second page')`

Comment: This error is showing:  `AssertError: Can not assert "This is first page" == "This is second page"`